# Excel colour formatting a row depending on current date

Tags: excel, date, colors

I have a spreadsheet that has a large list of virtual machines that I'm in control of. Each machine expires within 30 days of launch. Each machine has the expiry date recorded on the spreadsheet.

I want to be able to highlight each record to show:
Green - The machine is new and dont need to worry about it
Amber - The machines within 7 days of expiry so I can send out warnings
Red - The machines expired

Any help on this would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with either 3 conditional formats (1 for each colour) or 2 conditional formats plus a default background colour for the 3rd condition.  Then you need your conditions to be Less Than / Between / Equal To, and the value(s) should be `=TODAY()` or `=TODAY()-7`

If you want to highlight the whole row, rather than just the date, then you just need to use a Formula to determine which cells to format, and lock-down the Expiry Date column, e.g `=($C1=TODAY())` will apply to rows where a date in Column C is today's date